# string to number conversion in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Here is my simple program where I am trying to convert atom to string. I used `atom_number` for this.

code -

```
min(P1, P2) :-
    atom_number(P1, L1),
    atom_number(P2, L2)
    L1 > L2 ->
    (
        writeln('L2 id min'),
        writeln(L2)
    );
    L1 < L2 ->
    (
        writeln('L1 is mean'),
        writeln(L1)
    ).
```

when I execute the file -

```
swipl -s p1.pro
1 ?- min('12','13').
ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

similarly what if I want to know the data type of input parameter? apart from checking like `atom(L1), number(N2)` ?

Comment: Are you missing a comma behind L2) ? I also recommend stepping through with `?- gtrace, min('12','13').`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your if-then-else construct here: the atom-to-number conversion is only part of the first if-part. If that one succeeds, your predicate succeeds as well. For example:

```
?- ?- min('13','12').
L2 id min
12
true.
```

However, if the first if-part fails, the second if-part is evaluated. But this only consists of the inequality statement `L1 < L2` *without the atom-to-number conversions!*

The solution it to place the conversions before the if-then-else construct:

```
min(P1, P2):-
  atom_number(P1, L1),
  atom_number(P2, L2),
  (   L1 > L2
  ->  writeln('L2 id min'),
      writeln(L2)
  ;   L1 < L2
  ->  writeln('L1 is mean'),
      writeln(L1)
  ).
```

Now you get:

```
?- min('12','13').
L1 is mean
12
true.
```

Comment: @Woulter: thanks a lot. Is there any way to print the data type of input argument?

Comment: @user123 If you take a `Term` you can first check whether `compound(Term)` succeeds (for compound terms). Then `float(Term)`, then `integer(Term)`, then `atom(Term)` and then `var(Term)`. I believe that includes most of the types that occur in standard Prolog. SWI-Prolog has several additional datatypes that may or may not be supported by other implementations of Prolog [documented at this Web page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/datatypes.html).

Comment: @Wounter: but I guess not way to get the data type rather, like `datatype(term)` which gives `float` or `atom`

Comment: @user123 I'm indeed not aware of a built-in predicate that does this. You can use the following though: `datatype(Term, compound):- compound(Term). datatype(Term, float):- float(Term). datatype(Term, integer):- integer(Term). datatype(Term, atom):- atom(Term). datatype(Term, variable):- var(Term).` You can extend this with clauses for additional types, as you like.